# Vector force magnitude conversion to other direction

Tags: math, vector, physics, game-physics, physics-engine

I need some help on solving a simple vector force physics question.

Given a force vector (x, y), how to calculate the magnitude of the force apply on the direction (i, j) ?

(For example, given (1, 0) the magnitude of the force apply on the direction (0, 1) should be 0, and given (1, 0) the magnitude of the force apply on the direction (-1, 0) should be -1)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a programming question.

Comment: What mathematics do you know? Do you understand trigonometry? Dot products?

Comment: There's the clue: "dot product".

Answer (score 2):

It is just vector projection on another vector. It could be calculated as

```
ProjLength = DotProduct(F, A) / Length(A)
```

where F is force vector, A is direction vector

As far as I remember, in middle school we were taught to use cosine of angle between force and moving directions.